# Custom thumbnail image size in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the thumbnail size of an image in wordpress. I have seen in few other posts in SE that it can be done via `add_image_size()`.

Currently when I upload an image via add media it generates 4 files in the upload folder.

1.Thumbnail which is 150 x 150
2.Full
3.medium
4.Large

I just want to change the thumbnail size from 150 to 165.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have seen that post but somewhere I had a doubt that is add_image_size( 'thumb-small', 200, 200, true ); actually resizing the thumbnail?

Comment: Also thumb-medium refers to medium size ?